# Buttons in table row are not working after adding a row click function

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-4

I'm using bootstrap 4 and got a table where the table row is clickable. Also got two buttons in each row. But the buttons are no longer working as it is doing whatever the row click does.

here is a sample table

```
    <table id="subjects" class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="d-none">IDs</th>
                <th>Action</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr data-href="subjects/blah">
                <td nowrap class="d-none">
                    <div>121212</div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark" onclick="location.href='subject/fff'">Edit</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirm-delete" data-href="subject/delete/blah">Delete</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {


            $('.table tr[data-href]').each(function(){
                $(this).css('cursor','pointer').hover(
                    function(){ 
                        $(this).addClass('active'); 
                    },  
                    function(){ 
                        $(this).removeClass('active'); 
                    }).click( function(){ 
                        document.location = $(this).attr('data-href'); 
                    }
                );
            });
        });
    </script>
```

The first button has an onclick, the second button is opening up a bootstrap modal dialog.

At present none of these buttons work until I remove the table row jquery click function. How can I have this working nicely?

Comment: I think this is your solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31921334/bootstrap-table-row-clickable-with-buttons-in-row

Comment: you are correct! that did help me and is the same problem I was having. Thanks. If you want to post I can accept as the answer

Comment: I think this is your solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31921334/bootstrap-table-row-clickable-with-buttons-in-row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('.table td.row-link').each(function(){
  $(this).css('cursor','pointer').hover(
      function(){ 
          $(this).parent().addClass('active'); 
      },  
      function(){ 
          $(this).parent().removeClass('active'); 
      }).click( function(){ 
          document.location = $(this).parent().attr('data-href'); 
      }
  );
});
```